# How to use Postman Interceptor

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, google-chrome-devtools, postman

Ever since I upgraded to Postman 0.9.6 I can't replicate user sessions because chrome doesn't allow postman to get user cookies. However, they have decided to "work around" this issue by created another plugin called Postman Interceptor that routes your postman request and grabs the user cookies. They wrote a blog post about this wonderful tool here: http://blog.getpostman.com/index.php/2014/02/11/postman-v0-9-6-access-cookies-and-restricted-headers-plus-better-testing/

However, I can't seem to figure out how to get this thing to work. I have been trying for an hour now, and it still won't see my request as a logged in user

Comment: Can you please share your webrequest with us?

Comment: Postman Chrome app has been *deprecated* in the favor of native apps. So it is *better* to go for native app (in place of Chrome apps) which has direct support for intercepting cookies as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47692862/465053) post.  You will not require additional plugins like interceptor to check cookies when you use native apps.

Answer (score 75):

This worked for me:

1. Install [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client-packa/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en)
2. Install the [Interceptor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-interceptor/aicmkgpgakddgnaphhhpliifpcfhicfo)
3. Activate the Interceptor by toggling the switch:
   [image]
4. Activate the Interceptor in Postman by clicking on the "Capture requests" Button on the footer (has a satellite icon)
   [image: Capture button]

Comment: After following the above 4 steps, when you request a url in chrome, you can see your request history in the Postman history tab including request headers.

Comment: I don't see the 'satellite' icon... any ideas?

Comment: nope, maybe you are looking at the wrong place? I just installed it freshly and i can see it in the app

Comment: Huh... do I need to create an account / login? It definitely wasn't there... I'll try more tomorrow.

Comment: You can proceed to the app without loggin in, the link is pretty tiny though, compared to the login options ;)

Comment: I think my mistake was running the standalone 'Postman' application, rather than the Chrome App... *sigh* thanks!

Comment: if you want to add the User-Agent header for instance you don't have to turn on the interceptor in Chrome. It's enough with installing the extension and turning on the interceptor in the Postman client. Regards!

Answer (score 29):

To save someone having to dig through all the comments on related questions, here's a quick overview of the state of Postman in 2018:

## Standalone Postman (Current)

If you have a **satellite dish** icon you are using [standalone Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/):

[image: postman standalone screenshot]

**Postman Interceptor does not appear to work with the standalone Postman** (as of January 2018).

When you turn the satellite dish on, you are starting a proxy (default port: `5555`). If you update your browser and/or OS proxy settings to point to `localhost:5555`, the **requests made through the proxy will show up in Postman**, similar to how it worked with the old Interceptor.

You can read more about this feature [here](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/sending_api_requests/capturing_http_requests).

## Postman Chrome App (Deprecated)

If you have a **weird satellite thing** icon you are using the [old Chrome App](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop):

[image: postman chrome app screenshot]

This should work with the interceptor. See the instructions in [nozzleman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41564921/27581) if you are having trouble getting it to work.

**tl;dr You need to use the [Postman Chrome App](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop) if you want to use the [Interceptor extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-interceptor/aicmkgpgakddgnaphhhpliifpcfhicfo).**

Comment: Thank you for the answer!  I was having issues with the standalone app.  I notice the difference in icons.  I couldn't find any info in the documentation.  I just downloaded the Chrome App version of Interceptor and it displays the traffic in the History window!

Comment: I tried the stand alone app a few times but could never figure out how to intercept the ajax traffic from my client side web app (or any traffic really) until today with the help of this answer.    Thank you.  FYI, there is some documentation of the feature now.  Hadn't been able to find it before today.  https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/sending_api_requests/capturing_http_requests

Comment: Unfortunately, using Chrome on MacOS at least, it's necessary to proxy ALL HTTP and/or HTTPS traffic to capture any of it.  That's a lot of trust to be putting in an app installed from binary.  There is a work around described here.  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/244711/change-proxy-settings-for-chrome-and-not-for-entire-operating-system  Or you can just use a different browser like Firefox which has the ability to do manual proxy config instead of using system settings.

Comment: Thanks @shanemgrey. I updated the answer to link to the proxy documentation.

Comment: How do we set the proxy on macos? I tried http, https and socks but none worked. I get invalid certificate errors.

Answer (score 13):

Make sure to turn the Interceptor on in chrome and proxy on in Postman. Also ensure install correct extension! 
Oddly, it seems there are 2 postman Interceptor:

1. [Interceptor 1](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-interceptor/hfhmekcnabkelajbpjkinmhaplilkicm) <- Same name but not from getpostman.com
2. [Interceptor 2](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-interceptor/aicmkgpgakddgnaphhhpliifpcfhicfo) <- from correct source

Then it should work

Answer (score 4):

The issue for me was that I had multiple Chrome profiles, and requests with a non-main profile wasn't working, even if the extension was enabled. Once I switched to the primary profile and ensured the extension was enabled there, it started intercepting properly.

Comment: I think this might be affecting me... but I've installed the extension on both profiles, and it's still not working. Any ideas?

Comment: @Attie did you try closing the non-main profile window and visit the website with the main profile (to share those cookies)? Try quitting chrome and starting up with just the main profile. Ensure it's enabled properly as the main answer explains: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41564921/371699

Comment: Thanks, I did many of those things. Will try again tomorrow to be sure.

Comment: This is ridiculous but it was my problem.

Answer (score 3):

For native app POSTMAN(windows, macOS or linux) make sure you have installed the INTERCEPTOR Bridge:

https://community.getpostman.com/t/interceptor-integration-for-postman-native-apps/5290

Answer (score 1):

**Postman Interceptor integration is now available for Postman Native App ( > `v7.14.0`).**

- Download [Interceptor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-interceptor/aicmkgpgakddgnaphhhpliifpcfhicfo?hl=en) from Chrome Web Store. If you already have the extension, kindly ensure that the version is `v0.2.26` or later.
- Navigate to the Postman app and click the satellite icon in the upper-right corner to *Capture requests and cookies* with Postman. Install **Interceptor Bridge** either from *Cookies* tab or *Requests* tab with source toggled to Interceptor.

[image: Postman App - Install Interceptor Bridge]
[image: Postman App - Install Interceptor Bridge]

- Confirm Interceptor is ready to use by checking that the `INTERCEPTOR CONNECTED` status is green. You can now **capture browser requests** and **sync browser cookies** directly into Postman App. Learn more [here](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/interceptor/).

  [image: Postman Interceptor]
- Kindly note that you might need to restart Chrome before you see `INTERCEPTOR CONNECTED` status if you're using Postman App for Windows

> Note: If you face any issues while installing Interceptor Bridge, please check the [troubleshooting](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/interceptor/#troubleshooting-tips) doc. You can find the relevant information regarding Interceptor [here](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/interceptor/).

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways, and both works:

1) postman chrome app + postman interceptor plugin

Deprecated but more convenient, just a few clicks are needed.

2) postman native app

Officially recommended by not very user friendly. You have to manually change the  browser/system proxy setting.

Answer (score 0):

As some of them mentioned here Postman Chrome app is deprecated, you can not use it to intercept your API requests anymore.
Instead, Postman has released a beta version "Postman Canary", which works better.

Please follow these links to set up the canary and interceptor.
https://community.getpostman.com/t/interceptor-integration-for-postman-native-apps/5290

Answer (score 0):

Postman released Interceptor support for the packaged app for Mac / Windows / Linux in [v7.2.2](https://www.getpostman.com/downloads/release-notes#changelog-osx-app-7.0.7) in June 2019.

> 7.2.2: Added support for cookie syncing via the Interceptor

More about that here since the docs aren't updated yet: https://community.getpostman.com/t/interceptor-integration-for-postman-native-apps/5290

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work without Interceptor,just by disabling SSL

I was using older version of postman [Postman Chrome App (Deprecated)] in which I had to use interceptor,Basically I wanted to pass cookies as apart of Header.
Now when I tried to use New Standalone/Desktop Postman (Current tool),I got below error
[image]

To solve this error I just had to "**OFF**" SSL certificate verification.
[image]