# Remove origin header from postman request

Tags: postman

I'm using the Postman packaged app + the interceptor extension. It seems that chrome adds an `Origin: chrome-extension://aicmkgpgakddgnaphhhpliifpcfhicfo` header automatically for requests that come from Postman. I want to **remove** this header completely.

When using the Interceptor extension, if I use the regular Postman headers tab to enter an entry for the `Origin` header, then my request uses the specified value. So, I can **change** the value of the header. I then tried leaving the value field blank for the header, but then my request reverts to sending `Origin: chrome-extension://...`.

**How do I send a request with postman that either sends a blank `Origin` header, or totally omits it?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried it by myself and hope my solution will suit you.
When I make a POST request using Chrome app it adds `origin` header.

But when I use the **desktop app** no header is added to my POST request.

Here is an example of header sent by the desktop Postman app:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware they now have a desktop version :)

Comment: Note that you have to also install [Postman Interceptor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-interceptor/aicmkgpgakddgnaphhhpliifpcfhicfo?hl=en) as `Origin` is a restricted header. Read more [here](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/requests)

Comment: Thank you, this fixed it for me. 

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to use Postman desktop app (corporate policy yey!) so I'm stuck with Chrome extension Postman.

I was able to overwrite the Origin header by installing Postman Interceptor extension. You also need to active the Interceptor app in Chrome AND Postman. 
More detailed instructions can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41564921/1169726