# Google vision API rest integrartion

Tags: vision, google-cloud-vision

I am using trail version of google vision API ,using the rest API i am trying to get the face_detection values from postman tool but i am facing an issue showed below.can anyone help me on this.

```
"message": "Requests from referer chrome-extension://fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop are blocked.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the native Postman App. The Chrome app adds the "referer" header to every request it sends out.

Alternatively, you can try [enabling the Interceptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24472239/how-to-use-postman-interceptor), which will send requests through your browser, instead of through Postman.

Comment: Hello Aniket i have tried that unfortunately didn't worked

Comment: @mahesh, It's not possible that you will run into this error with the native app (because it doesn't even have anything to do with the chrome-extension). I recommend you uninstall the chrome extension, go to https://www.getpostman.com/apps and download the app for Linux/Windows/Mac, and try using that.