# How can I get session-id after login through instagram-api ? I am getting username but further api call I want session-id how will I get that?

Tags: instagram-api, instagram-graph-api, instagram-story

I am using Instagram login-api after that I am getting user details and username. But for further api calls I want session id also for that session how will I get that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract cookie from Instagram API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49820582/how-to-extract-cookie-from-instagram-api)

Comment: @MebinJoe Well, Cookie is cookie not a session.