# Postman get CSRF error when execute my request

Tags: postman

I use the postman request the bellow URL, it will get error:

http://localhost:8000/api/users/register/

the CSRF cookie error:

> CSRF Failed: CSRF cookie not set.

the settings of my request in postman:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

but if I write the request in PHP code then execute it there will not have this issue:

```
$params = array(
    "whmcs_tblclients_id" => 1232,
    "email" => "test22@qq.com",
    "username" => "asdas_asda",
    "phone" => "15883332126",
    "password" => "123456"
);

$request = Requests::post('http://localhost:8000/api/users/register/', array(), $params);
```

Comment: Are you using Postman chrome app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For send/recieve cookies you should enable Interceptor in Postman. **Refer**,

http://blog.getpostman.com/2014/11/28/using-the-interceptor-to-read-and-write-cookies/

**Refer** below to know `how to enable interceptor`,

[How to use Postman Interceptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24472239/how-to-use-postman-interceptor)

Additional to this, Postman Chrome app has been deprecated in the favor of native apps. So `it is better to go for native app` (in place of Chrome apps) which has direct support for intercepting cookies as mentioned in my answer. **Refer**,

http://blog.getpostman.com/2017/03/14/going-native/