# Postman POST return Forbidden after upgrade

Tags: post, postman

I upgraded Postman 8.0.2 to 9.29.5

In the older version I have POST calls that works, while in the newer I get `403: Forbidden.`

when I look at the cURL, I see that the newer version is adding also `--header 'Cookie: _xsrf=2|08cc..c6cc"'`.    all other parts of the calls are identical.

not sure why it's sending the extra parameter, and why it's causing the rejection.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a CSRF prevention causing some issues. I found another post mentioning similar issues.
[Postman get CSRF error when execute my request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52184880/postman-get-csrf-error-when-execute-my-request)

Comment: for those who will follow this link, pay attention to the instructions in https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/capturing-request-data/interceptor/
in the Installing Interceptor section.